# In project-security.xml, multiple http does not work

Tags: spring-security

I'm using security check url in separate http as follows:

```
 <security:http pattern="/j_spring_security_check" security="none"/>
```

Above code compile but in run mode login fails (always).

When I put this url in intercept-url inside http it works.

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
```

What is the reason it didn't work in the first place?

Comment: Because you are excluding the `/j_spring_security_check` from everything, including the processing of the login form when you put it in a seperate http block.

Comment: So what is the use of separate http block?

Comment: To not have security applied to certain URL which is something different as `permitAll` that will still apply all filters in the security chain, the other doesn't.